# How to have constants with specific associated methods

Tags: java

Suppose you have some class for storing information about attacks in a game (this is not my use-case, but is practically similar and the most understandable analogy I could think of). Every attack has a name (String) and a strength (int) (There would probably be other fields, but this is just an example). And you want some way to access information about every move in the game.

To me, this would be simple enough to implement using an `Attack` class, then storing every attack as finalized instances of `Attack` in some constants class `Attacks`.

But suppose some moves have a `strength` which varies under certain circumstances. For non-trivial behaviors, I would imagine one might need a specific method, which takes parameters (the "circumstances" under which said variation occurs) causes some additional effect, such as having a higher `strength` in certain circumstances, or healing the user, or weakening the target, etc.

I'm looking for a solution to the problem of needing what are effectively constants (all attacks are strictly defined in terms of their behavior), but with some having "optional" methods.

I have considered using functional interfaces/objects as a way of "passing" these methods to the class which actually handles the use of these attacks, but this seems unwieldy, and may lack flexibility.

Another possible solution would be to have an abstract `Attack` class, containing the necessary fields (`name`, `strength`, etc.) as well as a set indicating indicating whether or not the given attack has a certain property (all of the different possible properties being stored in an `enum` within the `Attack` abstract class). Every move would then be implemented as a subclass of `Attack` with methods corresponding to each property present in the aforementioned set. This solution offers a lot of flexibility, but would require individual classes for every single move, which would have to collected both in storage and in memory (perhaps as a map or set).

Any feedback on these ideas, or new ideas entirely, would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need individual classes for every single move, in the class-based approach?  It sounds like you'd only need classes for each different flavor of attack that does something specifically different.

Comment: Are you getting at subclasses? `Attack` has the common stuff and then gets extended by more specific subclasses with unique values?

Comment: It sounds fundamentally like a job for an `Enum`, with some context being passed to the methods so they can be context-aware.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I expect to have many different types of "attack", but not many different properties. E.g. there may be many attacks that have a `SECONDARY_EFFECT` property, but many different kinds of "secondary effect". All secondary effects might have the same method name and call (something like `secondaryEffect(user, target, environment){`), but the contents of the method would each be very different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a perfect usage for an *enum* in Java. You have a small fixed number of attack types which need to be treated polymorphically, and need customized behavior.

Simple example:

```
public enum Attack {
    MELEE(2) {
        @Override
        public int getDamage(int circumstances) {
            // customized behavior
        }
    },
    RANGED(1);

    private final int baseStrength;

    private Attack(int strength) {
        this.baseStrength = strength;
    }

    public int getDamage(int circumstances) {
        // default behavior for all attacks
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for my actual use case, I do not have a "small fixed number of attack types". I would like to have very many individual moves (to go along with the current context, say I attacks called Pierce, Trip, Entangle, Tackle, Bludgeon, Throw, etc.) all of which must have individual behaviors.

Regardless, this answer does provide some useful insight, and may still be usable. I would simply need an enum class with very many members (one for each unique move). With proper syntax, this would still be readable.

Comment: Sounds cool :) Yes, the enum approach should work nicely. If the implementation gets unwieldy you can break it up into the class equivalent: an abstract Attack class with subclasses for each attack type, all together in their own package.